# Location of Testng logs unless explicitly logged

Tags: java, testng, command-prompt, testng.xml

Overnight I was running test cases using the xmlsuite file from the Windows command prompt and I see that there was an exception when running test cases. Unfortunately I can't get back the buffer that left from the command prompt, so I was looking at made testng track last run and store the result/information in any place.

I would appreciate it if you could assist in retrieving the final details of the execution.